# sound generation on the fly

Tags: c++, audio, midi

I'm looking to generate sound on the fly given a set of parameters, and produce something along the lines of a midi to be played as it is created. Is this the best way to go about this? The important feature I'm looking for is control over the sound of the music, i.e., the instrument. Does anyone have suggestions on good sound libraries, apis?

Note, I'd rather not be reading and writing files constantly (e.g., generate a minute of audio, play that, and generate the next to be played)

Comment: Reply to this comment if you still want an answer. I have some resources for you but I'm away from computer right now. (mobile phone on a bus)

Comment: I would absolutely be interested in your resources! I'd put the project to rest, but i'd been looking to start work on it again.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could bore up some end-user programs like timidity or schismtracker, or libraries of the same, such as libmikmod, if you want sample mixing in midi/tracker-style.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of looking into Pure Data? You can run it on iOS/OSX and PC - and with that you could synthesise sound on the go without having to write anything. You can, of course, blend it with wavefiles if ya like.